# php script renders as a comment inside purchased template

Tags: javascript, php

I recently bought a template and started working on it. the template includes only html,css and javascript files. i have a problem that every php script i am trying to place inside the html filee, is being rendered as a comment. so when i try to add this script:

```
<?php
include_once "dbConnect.php";

//user name dropdown
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query); ?>
<select name="selectedName" id="userSelected">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
    <option value=""  >All</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['user_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['user_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<!--script name dropdown-->
<?php
$query = "SELECT script_name FROM scripts";
$result = mysql_query($query); ?>
<select name="selectedScript" id="scriptSelected">
    <option value="" disabled selected>script name</option>
    <option value=""  >All</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['script_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['script_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
?>
```

using this line:

```
<?php include_once "dropdown.php"?>
```

in the developer tool it appears like this:

```
<!--?php include_once "dropdown.php"?-->
```

any idea what can cause that? this code already worked in an html project i created and which im trying to move into this template.
*the template name its metronic

Comment: You need to give the file a `.php` extension, or change your webserver configuration to run all `.html` files through PHP.

Comment: looks like you are using some framework/ide that do this stuff, the file extension should be .php as others mention, but if that was the case you should be able to see it as a plain text and not as a comment, I think it is IDE that do this stuff, or maybe you are viewing the wrong files not the ones you modified, you should also try using include and not include_once

Answer (score 0):

the moment you place php in a HTML file, it is rendered as HTML. You should change the extension to .php then it will be able to run the PHP itself. (The HTML itself will not be affected)